# How to use filter or get method in Django Templates?

Tags: python, django

I have two tables, **document** and **publishermatter**

In **publishermatter**, I have one column **FK_doc** which is Foreign key of **document** table.

For one document, there are zero or more rows in **publishermatter** table.

I am passing document object to **Django Template** and and I want row with from publishermatter with specific condition where **key**(column name) is equal to **PAGECSS**(value)

I am doing in following way.

**Code 01**:

```
<div class="col-sm-7">
    {% for item in document.publishermatter_set.key %}
        {% if item.key == 'PAGECSS' %} 
            <p><br/>{{ item.key }} - {{ item.value }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Other way is to pass publishermatter from view by doing follwoing

`doc_obj.publishermatter_set.get(key='PAGECSS')`

But I want to do this in Template because I am passing documents objects from view.

Is there is any way in Django1.4 to filter query on Django template?

Comment: Although it doesn't affect the question, you should absolutely not be using Django 1.4; it is unsupported and insecure.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Yes, I agree. Django1.4 is no longer alive. But to support old Clients, I am using Django1.4, Client not want upgrade Django.

Answer (score 3):

You could indeed do this using custom template filters, but that's not the proper design IMHO in that it exposes model implementation details in places that shouldn't have to know about this.

A better solution here would be to just add the proper method to your model class:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    # your code here...

    # NB : may not be the best naming but I don't have enough
    # context to think of something better...
    def get_pagecss(self):
        # NB : only use `.get(...) if you have a unique 
        # constraint on (document, key) in Publishmatter
        # - else you want to use `filter(...)` and adapt
        # your template code to work on a queryset instead
        try:  
            return self.publishermatter_set.get(key="PAGECSS")
        except Publishmatter.DoesNotExist:
            return None # or anything that makes sense
```

and then in your template:

```
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    {% with document.get_pagecss as item %}
      {% if item%} 
        <p><br/>{{ item.key }} - {{ item.value }}</p>
      {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
  </div>
```

If you *really* want to expose what seems to be an implementation detail (AFAICT without more context) as part of the template layer you can of course go for a custom template filter. Assuming you already have some templatags file for your app ([if not just check the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout)), your filter could look like:

```
@register.filter
def publishmatter_get(obj, key):
    try:
        return obj.publishmatter_set.get(key=key)
    except Publishmatter.DoesNotExist:
        return None # etc...
```

and in your template:

```
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    {% with document|publishmatter_get:"PAGECSS" as item %}
      {% if item%} 
        <p><br/>{{ item.key }} - {{ item.value }}</p>
      {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
  </div>
```

Oh and yes, as Daniel Roseman rightly mentions: Django 1.4 is long dead, unmaintained, unsupported and insecure. I understand this might not be only up to you but you should **really** switch to a recent, supported release as soon as possible.

Comment: yes +1, I am using same method for other Tables. I just looking anything that can be directly write in Templates. Thank you for answer.

Comment: @VivekSable restrictions in Django template system are on purpose - if something can not be easily done in the template code then it probably doesn't belong to the template layer. The right question here is : is the issue _only_ a presentation issue (in which case it belongs to either the view or template layer) or is it something that makes sense as part of the "domain" layer. Only you (well, someone activeley working on the project that is) can answer this  question.

Comment: @VivekSable for the sake of completeness I added an example using a custom template filter.